# PHP- Issue on Escaping Quotations on AS SELECT

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Can you please take a look at following code and let me know how I can fix the `FROM  econo WHERE ".$collm."=1") ;";` part of the code to get rid of the disabling rest of the code error.
I already tried to replace `"` with `'` but this disable the `$collm` which I need it in the code

```
<?PHP
include 'conconfig.php';
$con = new mysqli(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASS,DB_NAME);
$collm = $_POST['column'];
$query = "SELECT x, y  FROM  econo WHERE ".$collm."=1";
$results = $con->query($query);
$return = array();
if($results) {
while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()) {
    $return[] = array((float)$row['x'],(float)$row['y']);
}
}
$query2 = "CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `charts_econo` (
          `id` int(12) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
          `econo_sum_projects` decimal(12,7) NOT NULL,
          `econo_sum_powerline` decimal(12,7) NOT NULL,
          `econo_sum_roads` decimal(12,7) NOT NULL,
          `econo_sum_cost` decimal(12,7) NOT NULL,
           PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
          ) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AS(SELECT COUNT(project),
                                            SUM(powerline_length),
                                            SUM(road_length),
                                            SUM(cost_per_year)
                                            FROM  econo WHERE ".$collm."=1") ;";
$con->query($query2);
$con->close();
echo json_encode($return);
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from 
`FROM  econo WHERE ".$collm."=1") ;";` 
to 
`FROM  econo WHERE ".$collm."=1) ;";`

if you really want to leave the quotes in there, you just had one too many.

Comment: Thanks visevo, looks like there is no error on the edittor now but when I try to query the table I am not getting any thing back now

Comment: if the SQL syntax is correct it's probably your query that is incorrect and just returning 0 rows. If that's not it, try debugging the query: `echo $query2; die();` and make sure that `$collm` has a value

Answer (score 1):

Just replace:

```
FROM  econo WHERE ".$collm."=1") ;";
```

with:

```
FROM econo WHERE $collm=1";
```

Comment: Hi Danijel using you method enables the other part of the code but how about the $collm it self which is gray out now?

Comment: In [double-quoted](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing) string variables are parsed within it.